# NPE error when running TestNg test groups using eclipse

Tags: nullpointerexception, testng

I am trying to run a Test group in TestNG by right clicking on TestNG.xml as a test suite and get below Error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at execution_Engine.TestCase1_Login.Login(TestCase1_Login.java:54)
```

Note: When I run the Test on its own(not as a Test suite) it runs fine.

Can anyone be kind enough to point out what the problem is? and solution to this problem.

TestNG.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Smoke tests">
<test name="regressions Test Suite">
    <groups> 
        <run> 
            <include name="Regression"/> 
        </run> 
    </groups> 
    <classes> 
        <class name="execution_Engine.TestCase1_Login"/> 
        <class name="execution_Engine.TestCase2_InvalidLogin"/>
    </classes>
            <packages>
        <package name="execution_Engine" />
        </packages> 
</test>
</suite>

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class TestCase1_Login  {

public static WebDriver driver = null;

 @BeforeMethod
  public static void LaunchIEandNavigate() {  

      /*** Launch IE **/ 
    System.setProperty "webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\IE\\IEDriverServer.exe");
      driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

      /*** implicit Wait **/
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      /*** Navigate to URL **/
      driver.get("http://google.com");



@Test(enabled = true, groups = "Regression")
public void Login() {

       /*** Login Action  **/
       driver.findElement(By.id("UserId")).sendKeys("DummyUser"); Line 54
       driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("password");
       driver.findElement(By.id("Submit-button")).click();

   System.out.println("Testcase1 - ValidLogin executed sucessfully.");

}

@AfterMethod
public void CloseIEandQuit() {
//driver.switchTo().defaultContent();   
  /** Close and quit browser*/
  driver.close();
  driver.quit();

}
```

Comment: You didn't specify the group on configuration methods. Another option is to set the alwaysRun=true.

Comment: @juherr - Thanks for your help. I updated the groups in configuration methods and also tried alwaysRun=true option, both worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Just Add (alwaysRun = true) to the @BeforeMethod annotation.

Comment: OMG I've been having the same error with @BeforeTest and this solved it. Thank you

Comment: Yes adding alwaysRun=true to BeforeTest resolved the issue.

Comment: Add 'alwaysRun' =true to @AfterMethod too. The above solution worked for me but it stopped executing AfterMethod, so after i added 'alwaysRun', it began to work correctly.

Comment: How to kiss someone in online :P lol.. Its help me lots

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:**

How to solve `NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION` while using grouping concepts in POM with Extends Reporting?

**Solutions:**

1. Use below parameters to all the configuration annotations which we are using i.e. in base test;
       (alwaysRun = true)
2. Use valid try catch block inside the page class and don’t use throws [incorrect exception]
3. Use parameterized values instead of taking hardcode values inside the page or script.

Answer (score 1):

To add to above answer, add (alwaysRun=true) to all the annotations you are using. I had annotation @BeforeClass along with @BeforeMethod. So add (alwaysRun=true) to all the annotations that form part of your test.

```
  @Parameters("browser")
  @BeforeClass(alwaysRun=true)
  public void setupDriver(String browser) 
  {
      application=new SSC_NewUserRegisteration(browser);

  }

  @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)
  public void launchApplication() 
  {
      application.app_launchApplication();
  }


  @Test(priority=1, groups = {"Valid Data"})
  public void submitWithAadharDetails() 
  {
      application.app_setTestData(1);

      application.app_fillNewUserRegisterationDetails();

      application.app_submitData();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Root cause is you have to add groups in your before method also or before class or alwaysRun.

Answer (score 0):

In order to Use testNG groups, only mentioning groups above test methods won't help, you needs to also enclose every test type method(suite, classes beforeMethod....) with some annotation for testNG to know to include it when its running test.

Something like  @AfterSuite(alwaysRun=true)